# I removed traces.txt file and cannot generate again

Tags: android, performance, adb, android-anr-dialog

Since my traces.txt file was too big, I wanted to remove it to make it from zero. I removed by `rm traces.txt` command. And now I am not able to see it again. I created it manually, but when I use `cat traces.txt` nothing happen because it is empty.

Here is the screenshot of the terminal. As you can see when I run the `cat traces.txt` nothing happens.

[image]

Currently I need that file to understand what causes **ANR** but I am not able to generate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should have generated the file again when I  run the application. It does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) on google developers guide,

> Android stores trace information when it experiences an ANR. On older
>   OS releases, there's a single /data/anr/traces.txt file on the device.
>   On newer OS releases, there are multiple /data/anr/anr_* files.

So I guess with your case as you have manually deleted the traces.txt file the only way to get it back is reproduce the ANR, probably after this the OS will generate a new traces.txt for you. Pull that file to some location on your computer via `adb pull`, then try reading it with an editor.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

After I uninstalled and installed the application, the file is created again. I do not know the exact reason yet, however now I can view the traces.txt file.

Comment: now the file is generated try adb pull as i mentioned instead of cat

Comment: When I type adb pull traces.txt it cannot see the file. When I enter the adb shell, it says `tmp-mksh: adb: not found.` Where should I run that command I am confused. Thanks

Comment: Run it on the computer/system (LinuxTerminal/WindowsCMD) directory. The system where your android device is connected.

Comment: @MangeshPawar Thank you so much. I ran this line `./adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt` and it copied file to the current directory.